# tikz draw line inside figure caption

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, captions, draw, line

Hi I draw some plot with  different line but it take to many place in plot, so I have try to draw a tikz line inside a figure caption, but it doesn't work inside a figure caption,

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
   line \tikz\draw [thick] (0,0.5) -- (0.5,0.5) ; 
   \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \includegraphics{image}
   \caption{Inside caption .\tikz\draw [thick] (0,0.5) -- (0.5,0.5) ;   }
   \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to just describe the line, e.g. *the thick black line shows ...*. A way around this is to use the optional argument to `\caption`, which holds a "short caption" that is placed in the list of figures. I.e. `\caption[in list of figures]{in document under figure}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

   line \tikz\draw [thick] (0,0.5) -- (0.5,0.5) ; 
   \begin{figure}[!ht]
   \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
   \caption[For list of figures]{Inside caption .\tikz\draw [thick] (0,0.5) -- (0.5,0.5) ;   }
   \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]